# Is it possible to generate mouse actions and keystrokes (similar to SendKeys) in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, mouseevent, sendkeys

I'm trying to write a code in Google Apps Script similar to something I do in VBA.
I need to manage a webpage (write some text, click some buttons) but I can't find any thread or text with Keystrokes or Mouse Actions in Google Apps Script.
In VBA would use mouse_event Lib "user32" and SendKeys.

Comment: Are you talking about simulating keystrokes from your computer to a 3rd party web page?  Why do you need to use Google App Script?  There are many simulators like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Comment: I need to load some forms in a specific web page (not mine). The info that I need to load in that page is already build by my team in a Google Sheet (stadard for our day to day activity). What I'm trying to automate is that loading which we do periodically. I already have something in VBA but if I could do it in G-Sheets, I could share it with my team in the same Sheet we alredy work. (we do have other automations but so far everything is in between Google Docs)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked everywhere and sadly I couldn't find a single post on favor but I've found a couple confirming that it is not possible.
I hope to find an alternative but so far the only one is VBA.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).